# Can't Get Facebook User Info While Login Using Hybrid Auth in CodeIgniter 3.0

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, hybridauth

How to get any information from facebook login like Email,Name,Phone Etc. I'm using Hybrid Auth in CODEIGNITER

I get This Array:-

The site url : [http://imedicalhub.nvkcoders.com/hauth/login/Facebook#*=*](http://imedicalhub.nvkcoders.com/hauth/login/Facebook#_=_)

```
Hybrid_User_Profile Object ( [identifier] => 955650971175283 [webSiteURL] => [profileURL] => [photoURL] => https://graph.facebook.com/955650971175283/picture?width=150&height=150 [displayName] => Lavish Tyagi [description] => [firstName] => [lastName] => [gender] => [language] => [age] => [birthDay] => [birthMonth] => [birthYear] => [email] => [emailVerified] => [phone] => [address] => [country] => [region] => [city] => [zip] => [username] => )
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Even though i have mentioned all the scopes facebook only returns identifier and profileURL.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use same account try different account.
dont use the account which has the facebook application. if you faced the same problem again then delete your app and recreate and try it again.
i hope this will help you,

Comment: Same Error With Different Account And With The New App Also..
Please Help Or Suggest Something New ....